# reading xml file in php excatly this type

Tags: php, xml

How can I read this type of XML file in PHP?

```
<AllPlatforms>
    <Phrase ID="YES">
        <en value="Yes"/>
        <fr value="Oui"/>
        <es value="Sí"/>
        <de value="Ja"/>
        <it value="Sì"/>
        <ru value="Да"/>
        <pl value="Tak "/>
        <tr value="Evet"/>
        <cz value="Ano"/>
        <se value="Ja"/>
        <pt value="Sim"/>
        <nl value="Ja"/>
    </Phrase>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

or

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

for a file!

It should look like this:

```
$xml = '<AllPlatforms>
    <Phrase ID="YES">
        <en value="Yes"/>
        <fr value="Oui"/>
        <es value="Sí"/>
        <de value="Ja"/>
        <it value="Sì"/>
        <ru value="Да"/>
        <pl value="Tak "/>
        <tr value="Evet"/>
        <cz value="Ano"/>
        <se value="Ja"/>
        <pt value="Sim"/>
        <nl value="Ja"/>
    </Phrase>';

$result = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```